# Progress Dialog appears weirdly on Pre-lollipop devices

Tags: android, progressdialog, android-styles

My progress dialog on pre-lollipop devices appears like this:
[image]

See that double window? I have no clue as to why this this happening.

**Code**

1. Initializing the progress dialog like this:

   ```
   progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
   progressDialog.setMessage(messsage);
   progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
   progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
   ```
2. Defined a style like this in values **and** values-21:

```html
<style name="AlertDialog.Theme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/black</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/orange</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/orange</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/darkerorance</item>
    </style>
```

3. After some searching on google, I added the alert style in my main theme like this:

```html
<item name="android:dialogTheme">@style/AlertDialog.Theme</item>
        <item name="dialogTheme">@style/AlertDialog.Theme</item>
        <item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/AlertDialog.Theme</item>
        <item name="alertDialogTheme">@style/AlertDialog.Theme</item>
```

And the main theme extends from `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`.

This works great on **Lollipop and above**, but appears like in the image on pre-lollipop. Can anyone help out here and tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't think there's a support version of ProgressDialog.

Comment: Not sure of your particular use-case, but as a general UI consideration, you might want to consider using a ViewFlipper with a loading view (e.g., FrameLayout with ProgressDialog) instead of a ProgressDialog. ProgressDialogs are blocking...so if your loading state gets hung or takes a while, the user is blocked from taking other actions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am a little late replying but this is how I got around solving it.
I created a separate `v-14` `styles.xml` and defined a style as shown below

**values-v14/styles.xml**

```
<style name="AlertDialog.Holo" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/Helvetica.Regular</item>
    <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@style/DialogTitleStyle</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

P.S - textAppearance and windowTitleStyle are styles I had created for the custom fonts.

**The regular (values/styles.xml) alert dialog style used is:**

```
<style name="AlertDialog.Theme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/zifycolor</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/zifycolor</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/zifycolorDarker</item>
    <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@style/DialogTitleStyle</item>
    <item name="buttonBarButtonStyle">@style/AlertDialogButtonStyle</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

**Finally to show a progress dialog:**

```
/**
 * Create a progress dialog. The appropriate theme gets applied.
 *
 * @param context  valid context with a window
 * @param messsage message to show
 * @return {@code ProgressDialog} instance
 */
public static ProgressDialog createProgressDialog(@NonNull final Context context, @NonNull String messsage) {
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context, R.style.AlertDialog_Theme);
    else
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context, R.style.AlertDialog_Holo);

    progressDialog.setMessage(messsage);
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    return progressDialog;

}
```

So far it works great! Hope it helps somebody.

Answer (score 3):

My workaround was the create a separate theme and style for pre-Lollipop with the parameter `android:windowBackground` as transparent. This removed the 2nd background in the back.

```
<style name="AppCompatAlertDialogStyleNoWindow" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

Then add this style as the `android:alertDialogTheme` for pre-Lollipop theme.

Comment: Only tested this API 16 and above

Answer (score 2):

Your answer is not working for pre-Lollipop (tested on API 19). But I find solution: you need to use `android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog` (in import settings)

Answer (score 0):

Dont style those dialogs, if u want to use material styles in pre lolipop devices,then make use of libraries

[Example](https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs)

Its very easy to use.

Comment: can we achieve this without using this library?

Comment: Library mentioned is open-source, u can obviously check the code and try to implement your own.  Libraries are meant to save your time.  For learning you can check up the code